# Facebook autoshare wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I tried to find a plugin that ask for access to a facebook app, if you confirm it, then each post that you visit should be automatically posted in the user wall. I have seen this example on several pages: www.hajgare.com, www.flej.eu
Since I couldn't find nothing yet I have started to build it by myself, this is what I have done so far: check if user is logged in to facebook and check if he has approved the app. if yes, then show the facebook share box (www.balkanews.net click on any news).

My question is how I can share without showing that facebook share box.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

            $(function(){

                liked = true;
                $("#trigger").click(function(){
                    if(liked){
                        post();
                    }else{
                        //alert('{L_FIRST_CLICK_LIKE}');
                        alert('like');
                    }
                });
            });


            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                    <!-- IF BOTH -->
                    liked = true;
                    <!-- ELSE -->
                    release();
                    <!-- ENDIF -->
                }); 
                FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            };
        <!-- ENDIF -->

        function release() {
            $("#item_container").hide();
            $("#real_container").show();
        }

        function post(){

            FB.init({appId: "409010965841527", status: true, cookie: true,        xfbml: true});
            FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    link:   document.URL,
                }, callback);
            setTimeout('move()', 100);
        }

        function callback(response) {
            if(response && response.post_id){
                release();
            }
        }

        function move(){
            $(".fb_dialog").css("left", "38px");
            setTimeout('move()', 400);
        }
    </script>

 <!- ///////////// -->
 <a href="javascript:;" id="trigger"><img src="./template/images/share.png" alt="" /></a>
 <script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.init({appId: '409010965841527', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(o) { 
   if (!o && o.status) return;
   if (o.status == 'connected') {
    //here goes the post code
    post();

   } else if (o.status == 'not_authorized') {
      window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=409010965841527&redirect_uri='+document.URL+'/&scope=user_about_me,publish_actions,user_likes';

   } else {
     window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=409010965841527&redirect_uri='+document.URL+'/&scope=user_about_me,publish_actions,user_likes';
   }
});

};

 (function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but you'll never get returning visitors because of annoying stuff like this. Go for better content instead. Sorry again.

Comment: I don't see any "WordPress" aspect to this question.

Comment: there may be a wordpress plugin for which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

your code is good but you are doing the wrong facebook publish action 
then dont use FB.ui
use Fb.Api that will solve your proplem example code

```
 function postToFacebook() {
    var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body ,message: 'I visited this post ' , link:'<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(get_the_ID()); ?>'}, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=409010965841527&redirect_uri='+document.URL+'/&scope=user_about_me,publish_actions,user_likes'; 
      } else {
        alert('Post published '); // you can del this alert 
      }
    });
}
```

and that's it
let me know if this code worked for you and post your final code